# Modify MP3 properties using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to modify the properties of the mp3 files. 
The properties such as artist, album, title and so on. I need to alter those fields.

Only in javascript. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Javascript language doesn't contain functions to read to and from files which is required to modify ID3-tags.

However, depending on the Javascript engine and environment, such functions may or may not be available in the library that engine/environment provides. Eg. it is possible to do this in a Javascript running under [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/), since Rhino exposes the classes included with Java.

Comment: Link doesn't work btw

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. Although my experience with JavaScript is limited, I believe it runs in a sandbox and it's not allowed to perform operations outside of the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

This link should provide some hints and code you could use:

[Ajaxian: Reading ID3 tags with JavaScript](http://ajaxian.com/archives/reading-id3-tags-with-javascript)

Here is a [demo](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/id3/), which uses a file you have to upload.

Comment: Demo link is broken btw